Do conjunctions like "and" ever become grammaticalized into plural morphemes?
If so, what are some examples of this having occurred?
For instance, take a scenario where "X-and-X" is a common expression of plurality, as in English emphatic quantitative expressions like "lots and lots", "hundreds and hundreds", "miles and miles". If such a construction were very frequent, could "X-and" or "and-X" be reinterpreted as a plural affix? Has anything like this ever been observed?

I suppose one might argue that the reduplicative plurals found in various Polynesian and other East Asian languages is quite similar to this, even though there’s no actual and in those (it’s just hundred-hundred or mile-mile to make the plural).

@JanusBahsJacquet Thanks, I'm aware of this pattern. I'm looking specifically for the grammaticalization of conjunctions in plural morphemes.

The closest examples of this phenomenon I can think of can be represented by some varieties of African American Vernacular English (AAVE) that have expressions like: "Sarah dem coming today."  In standard English this might be: "Sarah and the others/her friends/family are coming today."  The word "dem" refers to a group that is obvious from the context; and "Sarah" marks a situationally prominent member of the group.  I think in some forms of Caribbean English the morpheme "dem" can be used as a general marker of plurality (See, e.g., Jamaican Patois and the Power of Language in Reggae Music by Stacey Herbold).
The derivation of "dem" is not clear to me beyond its obvious relationship to standard English "them."  It is almost definitely an approximate calque of one or more West African languages with similar expressions.  I have heard AAVE variants like "Sarah and dem" with an explicit conjunction used to express the same meaning as "Sarah dem," but I am not sure whether that form comes from an older pattern or is just a later remodeling of the pattern that seems closer to standard English.
The West African languages with this type of expression include some form of pronoun whose derivation is unclear to me.  It is conceivable that at least some of them derive from expressions including a morpheme meaning "with."  In at least one of them, the pattern can also reduplicate the usage of "and" used to join nouns into a single noun phrase.  An example of this pattern using AAVE vocabulary would be "Sarah dem John coming today" as an equivalent of standard English "Sarah and John are coming today"; however, this pattern is not grammatical in the AAVE I am familiar with.
